# time taken to parse and simplyify a CNF file

Tags: java, sat, sat4j

I have just starting to use the Sat4j libraries. Can you direct me how to calculate the time taken  to parse and simplify a given CNF input.

i have used

```
ISolver solver = SolverFactory.newDefault();
Reader reader = new DimacsReader(solver);
IProblem problem = reader.parseInstance(filename.cnf);
boolean check=problem.isSatisfiable();
```

i wish to calculate the time taken by the reader to parse and isSatisfiable.
if possible kindly direct me to find the information in the image for every cnf file processed
[screenshot of the details i look to collect using sat4j lib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKT8k.png)
Thank you for your time in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I try to embedded your source code in an old fashion way to get the execution time.

```
Date startDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
long d_StartTime = new Date().getTime();

    ISolver solver = SolverFactory.newDefault();
    Reader reader = new DimacsReader(solver);
    IProblem problem = reader.parseInstance(filename.cnf);

Date endDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
long d_endTime = new Date().getTime();

System.out.format("Milli = %s, ( D_Start : %s, D_End : %s ) \n", (d_endTime - d_StartTime),d_StartTime, d_endTime);

boolean check=problem.isSatisfiable();
```

With this, the time in milliseconds to parse the instance will appear :).
I hope this help !